# Multiple CASE Select in SQL

Tags: sql

I am working with a database which stores some object info but also three images stored in a byte array. When I query all the images at once the query gets extremely slow. So the idea is to lazy load the images once I got all the other data, but I need to know if the object actually got an image to trigger the lazy load afterwards. So I looked into the CASE sql statement which seem promising but I got a problem:

This is my current sql query:

```
SELECT Title,
   'hasBackImg' = CASE WHEN BackgroundImage IS NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END,
   'hasForeImg' = CASE WHEN ForegroundImage IS NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END,
   'hasDetailImg' = CASE WHEN DetailsImage IS NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END
FROM Object;
```

I did some testing and it seems, if an object actually got a BackgroundImage it returns True for all three images even though the other two images are NULL, like this:

```
Test1 | False | False | False
Test2 | True | True | True
```

but it should be:

```
Test1 | False | False | False
Test2 | True | False | False
```

So maybe somebody can tell me what I'm doing wrong or even better if there is a different way to query for existing values without getting the whole value.

Thanks

EDIT:
Turns out the value for no image in the database was set to an empty byte array not null so I just updated my model to update an empty image to null and now it works.

Comment: You are comparing the string constant `'hasBackImg'` with the result of the CASE expression which is either `'False'` or `'True'` those values will never be equal  - **all** those expressions should be `false` actually

Comment: Can you provide some examples with 3 informations: (1) the row in the `Objects` table, (2) the desired output and (3) the actual output

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT Title,
   CASE WHEN BackgroundImage='hasBackImg'  THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END,
        WHEN ForegroundImage='hasForeImg'  THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END,
        WHEN DetailsImage='hasDetailImg' THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END
FROM Object;
```

Answer (score 0):

If three images stored in a byte array, then you can use `operator IIF` or `operator CASE`:

```
--operator case:
--Column's alias is pointed after statement END
SELECT Title,
    CASE WHEN BackgroundImage IS NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END AS hasBackImg,
    CASE WHEN ForegroundImage IS NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END AS hasForeImg,
    CASE WHEN DetailsImage IS NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END AS hasDetailImg
FROM Object

--if you are using sql server, then can try operator IIF:
 SELECT Title,
    IIF( BackgroundImage IS NULL, 'False' , 'True' ) AS hasBackImg,
    IIF( ForegroundImage IS NULL , 'False' , 'True') AS hasForeImg,
    IIF( DetailsImage IS NULL , 'False', 'True')    AS hasDetailImg
FROM Object
```

Comment: schinkenwurfel, do you try this?)

Comment: I did try it and it made me realize that the data in my database was wrong. See my edit. But thanks anyways